# Using .txt file from resources and copy random lines to textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I had a code that works like a charm when I put .txt in my c:\
But I want to read that .txt from my resources

here is the code that don't work

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    NAMES.Clear()
    Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader(My.Resources.names)
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Dim line As Integer
    While ioFile.Peek <> -1
        lines.Add(ioFile.ReadLine())
    End While
    line = rnd.Next(lines.Count + 1)
    NAMES.AppendText(lines(line).Trim())
    ioFile.Close()
    ioFile.Dispose()
    Clipboard.SetText(NAMES.Text)
    NAMES.Text = Clipboard.GetText()
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("^(V)", True)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Is there an error? What line gives the error and what is the error? If you don't get an error what happens that is different from what you expect.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll @Mary

Comment: I can see where you would get an index out of range error with Count +1. i realize that the argument for .Next is exclusive but the indexes for lines start at 0 and go to Count -1.

Comment: What line causes the error? I tried your code and I don't get an error.

Comment: When you insert a text file into the application's resources, it will be converted to a  `String`, so you just need to do: `NAMES.Text = My.Resources.names`

Comment: And, to get list/array of lines, you could do: `Dim arrNames() As String = My.Resources.names.Split({ControlChars.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: Your stream reader will not be closed and disposed if there is an error. Use `Using...End Using`.

Comment: @JQSOFT Yes, but the string is a path to the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204643/discussion-between-mary-and-jqsoft).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a New Random each time you call the code. Move the declare outside the method. I substituted `File.ReadAllLines` for the stream reader. It does all the work in one line, opens, reads and closes the file. No need to use a List here. The array behaves the same with the indexes.

I don't see why you are using `.AppendText`. You clear all the text at the top of the code so, there is nothing to append to. If you want to see each random name then don't clear the text box and use `.AppendText`. Starting with a new line, or a comma and a space.

I don't understand what the `Clipboard` and `SendKeys` are supposed to accomplish. You are pasting the same text back into the text box. The Tab key doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(My.Resources.names)
    Dim index As Integer
    index = rnd.Next(lines.Count)
    TextBox1.Text = lines(index).Trim()
End Sub
```